# Not able to set initial values of formik form?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have created a formik form that gets its initial values from the backend database through API calls. Got below error:

> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'FormikValues'.  TS2322

Not able to resolve the error.

code:

```
// @ts-ignore

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import {
  Typography,
  Button,
  Grid,
  CircularProgress,
  Divider,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { MyInput } from './comman/MyInput';
import axios from 'axios'
import ThumbUpAltIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt';
import Unsubscribed from './Unsubscribed';

const contactSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  });
export default function SurveyUnsubscribed(props: any) {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  //const [color, setColor] = useState(true);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [countone, setCountOne] = useState(0);
  const [counttwo, setCountTwo] = useState(0);
  const [countthree, setCountThree] = useState(0);
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    msg: '',
  });
  let initial:any;
  
async function getInitialValues() {
  try{
    const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST_DEVELOPMENT_VOTING_API_GET}`)
    return response.data;
      }catch(error){
    console.error(error)
  }
}


  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialValues().then((res:any) => setInitialValues(res));

    }, []);


  const handleClickCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    // setColor(false);
  };
  const handleClickCountTwo = () => {
    setCountTwo(counttwo + 1);
    // setColor(false);
  };  const handleClickCountThree = () => {
    setCountThree(countthree + 1);
    // setColor(false);
  };  const handleClickCountOne = () => {
    setCountOne(countone + 1);
    // setColor(false);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Formik
        enableReinitialize
        initialValues={initialValues}
          // count: initial,
          // countone: countone,
          // counttwo: counttwo,
          // countthree: countthree,
          // helptext: '',
        
        validationSchema={contactSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
          setLoading(true);
          console.log(initial)
        
          const data = {
            count: values.count,
            countone: values.countone,
            counttwo: values.counttwo,
            countthree: values.countthree,
            helptext: values.helptext,
          };
          console.log(data);
          const request = new Request(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST_DEVELOPMENT_VOTING_API}`,
            {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              }),
              body: JSON.stringify(data),
            },
          );

          fetch(request)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
              if (data.message === 'Thank you for your feedback!') {
                setState({
                  msg: data.message,
                });
                setIsSubmitted(true);
                setTimeout(() => {
                  setLoading(false);
                }, 1500);
              } else {
                console.log('error');
              }
            });
          setTimeout(() => {
            setIsSubmitted(false);
          }, 1500);

          resetForm();
        }}
      >
        {({ setFieldValue }) => (
          <Grid container>
            <Grid
              item
              xs={12}
              style={{ paddingLeft: '2em', paddingRight: '2em' }}
            >
              <Typography
                variant="h6"
                style={{
                  marginTop: '1em',
                  color: '#2F4858',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                }}
              >
    Voting survey          </Typography>
              <br />
              {isSubmitted}
              <Form>
                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  <Field type="hidden" name="count" component={ThumbUpAltIcon}  onClick={handleClickCount} style={{ color: '#C4C4C4', marginRight: '0.4em' }}/>
                  <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      top: '1.5em',
                      right: '1.5em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {count}
                  </Typography>
   A             </Typography>

                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  <Field type="hidden" name="countone" component={ThumbUpAltIcon}  onClick={handleClickCountOne} style={{ color: '#C4C4C4', marginRight: '0.4em' }}/>
                  <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      top: '1.5em',
                      right: '1.5em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {countone}
                  </Typography>
  B              </Typography>

                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  <Field type="hidden" name="counttwo" component={ThumbUpAltIcon}  onClick={handleClickCountTwo} style={{ color: '#C4C4C4', marginRight: '0.4em' }}/>
                  <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      top: '1.5em',
                      right: '1.5em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {counttwo}
                  </Typography>
 C               </Typography>

                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  <Field type="hidden" name="countthree" component={ThumbUpAltIcon}  onClick={handleClickCountThree} style={{ color: '#C4C4C4', marginRight: '0.4em' }}
                   />
 
                  <Typography
                    variant="caption"
                    style={{
                      position: 'relative',
                      top: '1.5em',
                      right: '1.5em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {countthree}
                  </Typography>
D
                </Typography>

                <br />
                <Typography
                  variant="h6"
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: '2em',
                    marginTop: '0.5em',
                  }}
                >
                  What information would help you ?
                </Typography>
                <Field
                  id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
                  type="text"
                  name="helptext"
                  component={MyInput}
                  disabled={isSubmitted}
                  style={{ marginLeft: '2em' }}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                 
                    style={{
                    background: '#2F4858',
                    color: 'white',
                    fontFamily: 'roboto',
                    fontSize: '1rem',
                    marginLeft: '2em',
                    marginBottom: '1em',
                  }}
                >
                  {loading && (
                    <CircularProgress
                      size={25}
                      color="inherit"
                      style={{ marginRight: '5px' }}
                    />
                  )}
                  {loading && <span>submitting</span>}
                  {!loading && <span>Submit</span>}
                </Button>
                <br />
                {state.msg && (
                  <Typography
                    variant="h6"
                    style={{
                      color: '#4BB543',
                      fontFamily: 'roboto-medium',
                      marginTop: '1em',
                    }}
                  >
                    {' '}
                    {state.msg}{' '}
                  </Typography>
                )}
              </Form>
              <Divider
                style={{
                  border: '1px solid #97A1A8',
                  marginTop: '1em',
                  marginBottom: '2em',
                }}
              />
              <Unsubscribed />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

please guys help me with setting `formik` **initial values** from the database(Postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you create state `initialValues` with default value is `undefined`. So just update default value to an empty object

```
const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Viet. But got new error "Property 'count' does not exist on type '{ initialValues: undefined; }'"